# Linked List using generics, getting "not applicable arguments for parameters" error

Tags: java, generics, data-structures, linked-list

My Node class:

```
public class Node<T> 
{
    protected T data;
    protected Node<T> next;
    protected Node<T> previous;

    public Node()
    {
        this.data = null;
        this.next = null;
        this.previous = null;
    }

    public Node(T data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
        this.previous = null;
    }

    public Node(T data, Node<T> next, Node<T> previous)
    {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;
        this.previous = previous;
    }

    public T getData() 
    {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) 
    {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Node<T> getNext() 
    {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(Node<T> next) 
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Node<T> getPrevious() 
    {
        return previous;
    }

    public void setPrevious(Node<T> previous) 
    {
        this.previous = previous;
    }
}
```

My LinkedList class:

```
public class LinkedList<T extends Node<T>>
{   
    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;
    private Node<T> currNode;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        currNode = null;
    }

    public LinkedList(Node<T> head)
    {
        this.head = head;
        tail = head;
        currNode = head;
    }

    public void resetHead()
    {
        currNode = head;
    }

    public void add(T data)
    {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(data);

        newNode.next = null;

        if(head == null)
        {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
           tail.next = newNode;
           newNode.previous = tail;
           tail = newNode;
        }

    }

    public void addHead(T data)
    {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(data);

        newNode.next = head;

        head.previous = newNode;

        head = newNode;
    }

    public void addAfter(T data, Node<T> previousNode)
    {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(data);

        newNode.next = previousNode.next;

        previousNode.next = newNode;
    }

    public void addBefore(T data, Node<T> nextNode)
    {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(data);

        newNode.next = nextNode;

        nextNode.previous = newNode;
    }

    public void delete(Node<T> nodeToDelete)
    {
        (nodeToDelete.getNext()).setPrevious(nodeToDelete.getPrevious());
        (nodeToDelete.getPrevious()).setNext(nodeToDelete.getNext());
        nodeToDelete.setNext(null);
        nodeToDelete.setPrevious(null);
    }

    public boolean hasNext()
    {
        if(head == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(currNode.next != null)
        {
            currNode = currNode.getNext();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean hasPrevious()
    {
        if(tail == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if(currNode.previous != null)
        {
            currNode = currNode.getPrevious();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public Node<T> getHead() 
    {
        return head;
    }

    public void setHead(Node<T> head) 
    {
        this.head = head;
    }

    public Node<T> getTail() 
    {
        return tail;
    }

    public void setTail(Node<T> tail) 
    {
        this.tail = tail;
    }

    public Node<T> getCurrNode() 
    {
        return currNode;
    }

    public void setCurrNode(Node<T> currNode) 
    {
        this.currNode = currNode;
    }
}
```

The error crops up when attempting to use any of the add/insert methods in LinkedList. For example, if I try to use the `add(T data)` method, like so: `listOfChars.add('B');`, I get the following error: `The method add(Node) in the type LinkedList is not applicable for the arguments (char)`. What I expect it to do is to accept the data (in this case, the char 'B'), create a new node with 'B' as the data, and then put it in the linked list after the last node in the list. From my understanding, the method is expecting a Node instead of any generic data type, such as a char.

After doing some researching, I think somewhere in my TestLinkedList class, I have declared the LinkedList object incorrectly:

```
public class TestLinkedList 
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Node<Character> n1 = new Node<Character>('A');

        LinkedList listOfChars = new LinkedList(n1);

        listOfChars.add('B');
    }
}
```

but I can't figure out how to declare it correctly. I've tried `LinkedList<Character>`, `LinkedList<Node>`, `LinkedList<Node<T>>`, and `LinkedList<Node<Character>>`, but none of them are correct. Any help would be appreciated as this is my first time using generics and I am just trying to learn how to apply it to a Linked List I've made.

Comment: Why does your linked list need to have `T extend Node<T>`? Surely it should be just `public class LinkedList<T>`

Comment: @AshFrench I thought LinkedList had to be a subclass of Node to be able to have proper access to it to work. I'm still not 100% clear on why it doesn't need to extend Node<T>, but I understand why extending Node<T> was causing an issue in the add/insert methods. If you could explain why LinkedList works without extending T, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @AlexFinkel, sorry for taking time to get back to you. Think of generics as a global find and replace, everywhere in your class where you put `T` you can put in another class, in your case `Character`. If you then follow this through, when you put `<T extends Node<T>>` it will mean that your methods `addData` would become `addData(Node<Node<Character>>)`.

Comment: In terms of accessing `Node`, it is a public class, so anyone is allowed to have access to it. But since your variables in Node are protected it means anything that extends Node or is in the same package as Node can access those variables, and in turn says why your `LinkedList` class can call `node.next`. Have a look at what happens when you set the variables inside no to private, `LinkedList` would not compile due to not having access to it. If you are struggling have a read of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html.

Comment: @AshFrench I was under the impression that `protected` only allowed for extended classes to have access to it, thanks for clearing that up. Out of curiosity, how would I declare an extension properly? Would it be `LinkedList<T> extends Node<T>`? I think that threw an error the first time I tried it, and after some searching around I saw that it should be declared `LinkedList<T extends Node<T>>` which is what led me to this whole issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fix two things. First, the class declaration of LinkedList says:

```
public class LinkedList<T extends Node<T>> {
```

which means that T has to be both a Node and the element of a Node. This doesn't work with Character since a Character is not an instance of Node. If you remove the constraint so that T can be any value, it works with Character.

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
```

Next you should add the generic part to the main file for the listOfChars as well:

```
LinkedList<Character> listOfChars = new LinkedList<Character>(n1);
```

Also make sure that you have imported the right LinkedList and not the java standard class.

Comment: I knew I was declaring it incorrectly, but when I tried `LinkedList<Characters> listOfChars = new LinkedList<Character>(n1);` it still wasn't working due to the class declaration being wrong. Thank you for the succinct explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You simply have to rewrite `LinkedList` from

```
LinkedList<T extends Node<T>>
```

to

```
LinkedList<T>
```

since in the code of `LinkedList` you already state that you are using `Node` objects.

You can use it like this:

```
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Node<Character> n1 = new Node<>('A');

        LinkedList<Character> listOfChars = new LinkedList<>(n1);

        listOfChars.add('B');
    }
```

Comment: and when he is declaring a new `LinkedList` it should be `LinkedList<Character> listOfChars = new LinkedList<>(n1)`

Answer (score 2):

I think its a combination of both Todd's and Adams answer

```
public class LinkedList<T extends Node<T>>
```

to

```
public class LinkedList<T>
```

and

```
LinkedList<Character> listOfChars = new LinkedList<>(n1);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can infer from the error `The method add(Node) in the type LinkedList is not applicable for the arguments (char)`
This is a type error, your add method expects a Node but in the main you call add with type character.

Your LinkedList class is expecting an object of type T extends Node. Which would imply a custom class that extends your Node object, however that is not what you are looking to use to add objects to the linkedlist.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so your class declaration 
`public class LinkedList<T extends Node<T>>`
is saying 'This is a class LinkedList parameterised by `T` where `T` is a subtype of `Node<T>`

This means if you wanted `T = Character` for example, you would need `Character` to be a subtype of `Node<Character>`, which doesn't really make sense.

You probably want to just parameterise your class by `T` eg `public class LinkedList<T>`

Then you can go `LinkedList<Character> listOfChars = new LinkedList<Character>(n1)`

or more succinctly `LinkedList<Character> listOfChars = new LinkedList<>(n1)` as the second generic parameter can be inferred

Answer (score -2):

Create your LinkedList like this:

```
LinkedList<Character> listOfChars = new LinkedList<>(n1);
```

EDIT:
M4ver1k is right that this alone won't fix it.  I missed the part that Adam Arold pointed out.  Adam's answer fixes the problem and should be accepted.  My answer just prevents the LinkedList from being implicitly defined as a `LinkedList<Object>`.

.

Comment: This wont fix the issue and can u please explain how to came up with this answer ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I missed the key issue that Adam saw and was too quick to pull the trigger.  Lesson learned.  The change I suggested is somewhat cleaner but isn't actually necessary to make the test code work.